# How to print all DFA states in ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr4

everyone,

I'm just starting to learn how things work. I have built my example parser for Java-like language and I would like to see how the engine makes its decisions. For example GNU Bison could produce report file with DFA states in a text form

State XXX

Could I generate similar report using ANTLR? I'm using ANTLR 4. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use additional parameter of command line: -Xdfa

Comment: Is there any truth to this? I can't get it to work and don't see documentation on it.

Comment: For antlr3 it work. `-Xdfa` processed in `Tool::processArgs`. Perhaps there is an analog in antlr4.